# in php just take custome word from line

Tags: php

I have a line and I want to use PHP to make some changes to the line. Basically,  in this line, `ip` and `port` and `password` can be changed to anything.

```
$mod = +connect "79.175.163.234:27015" +password ""
```

and I just need this part :

```
+connect "ip:port"
```

and if ther word password is something other than password then return this:

```
+connect "ip:port" +anything-can-be-here ""
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is the first line supposed to be a string? Can you show some full examples?

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
// plus not allowed  concatenation string in php you can use dot (.)
<?php
        $ip = "79.175.163.234:27015";
        $password = "123456";
        echo $mod .= "connect ".$ip." ".$password;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ip = "79.175.163.234:27015";
$password = "123456";
$mod += "connect ".$ip." ".$password;
```

Comment: Thanks but as i say it is one line : +connect "79.175.163.234:27015" +password "" returned from function result and i cant use sepret $ip and $password becuas of that i need to do what i say in first post